# Find when data is read from a DOM element with chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, devtools, byte-order-mark

I am debugging an issue where text contained in a textbox is later used as a query parameter in a request. However the text is being modified somewhere along the way (specifically byte order marks (BOM) are being inserted) and I am ensure why. I would like to put a breakpoint in the surrounding code where this text box is accessed to figure out what is happening.

Comment: If you can provide your code and structure, it can help to understand what is going on

Comment: Well if I provided the source it would be easy :P This is more of a generic question - how would one debug this issue?

Comment: Hey, we all want easy. Easy questions and easy answers, easy life :D you would want to start at either end of your chain. how are you recording the information on your page, how are you referencing it? are you using third party librarys, like JQuery? What does your data look like to start, how would you like it to end up looking?

Comment: It's not my page, hence the ambiguous tone of the question :P I am not looking for the answer to my problem - I am looking for advice on how to solve it. It seemed like a common enough issue to post to stack overflow to hopefully have others benefit from in the future :)